# How to avoid two flavours of an app opening the same app?

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors, android-flavordimension

I have different flavours configured for my application. When I install both flavours on the same device there is a huge problem.

When I open App1(Flavour 1) and then minimise it(Click on Home button) and try to open App2(Flavour 2) it opens App1(Flavour1). In order to open App2 I have to kill App1 from recents and then open App2. This happens vice versa too.

I tried using different flavour dimensions too. Here is my current configuration.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
flavorDimensions("default")
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.aa"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
}

productFlavors {
    aa {
        applicationId "com.xx.aa"
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.0.1"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appName: 'aa',
                appId  : 'com.xx.aa'
        ]
        buildConfigField "boolean", "XXXX", "false"
    }
    bb {
        applicationId "com.xx.bb"
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.2.3"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appName: 'bb',
                appId  : 'com.xx.bb'
        ]
        buildConfigField "boolean", "XXXX", "true"
    }
}
```

My Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xx.aa">

<!-- few permissions-->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".global.aaApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_default"
    android:label="${appName}"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_default"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppCompactTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
.
.
.

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: in my case, I use in `defaultConfig { applicationId "com.xx" }` and `flavorDimensions "aa"` right before `productFlavors { ... }`

Comment: what logic do you have in your `.global.aaApplication`

Comment: can you post it too

Comment: If there (aaApplication) some specific logic for your `com.xx.aa` app?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `applicationId "com.xx.aa"` from the `defaultConfig`. You don't have to specify here when you are using `productFlavors`.

Comment: Tried it still the same behaviour no change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your exact objective, below task will stop your app before launch.

```
task stopApp(type: Exec) {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
            if (variant.flavorName == flavor.name) {
                def applicationId = [variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId, flavor.applicationIdSuffix].findAll().join()
                def command = ['adb', 'shell', 'am', 'force-stop', applicationId]
                commandLine command
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add this task to your `Run Configuration` > `Before launch`.

Or simply (if it's OK) add `uninstallAll` task.

[image: enter uninstall gradle task]

Comment: Im getting this problem in runtime. Even after deplying two flavours of the app to play store im facing this issue.. Using the above task wont help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you are specifying "com.xx.aa" as your package. This can cause problems between both or your apps (aa and bb). Also remove it from your defaultConfig.

I have an app with several flavours all with the same manifest package but in order to install them all in the same device I change applicationIdSuffix parameter and all the app can be used at the same time.

Comment: I cannot remove the package name from my manifest. If I do that I cannot specify the activity names in my manifest file. Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Remove your applicationId from your aa and bb flavour config and then user applicationIdSuffix (= ".aa" for aa and = ".bb" for bb).

Comment: I recommend you to read: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables and https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id